# Edit axis. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to edit my axis's graphic but it is not working when I use `plt.yticks([])`. The program is still showing me the values. Can you help me remove them?

Maybe the problem is because I am using canvas?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import animation
import random

# Create the Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x100')

fig1, b1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 0.5), dpi = 80,)
b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
plt.yticks([])

fig2, b2 = plt.subplots(figsize= (10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
plt.yticks([])


def grafico_1 (i):


    global b1
    global nume
    global valu
    global fig1
    global y_fix
    global x

    x = []
    y_fix = []
    ws = ['WIRE']

    for valu in range (1, 6):
        nume = random.randint(1, 10)
        x.append(nume)
    #print(x)
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x[0]) < 3:
        y_fix.append(int(x[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x[0]) >= 3 and int(x[0]) < 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c in x[1:]:

        if int(c) < 3 :

            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color= 'green', left=y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
            
        if int(c) > 3 and int(c) < 5:
        
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='yellow', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)

        if int(c) >= 5:
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='red', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
    #fig1 = plt.yticks([])

def grafico_2 (i2):


    global b2
    global nume2
    global valu2
    global fig2
    global y_fix2
    global x2

    x2 = []
    y_fix2 = []
    ws2 = ['line 2']

    for valu2 in range (1, 6):
        nume2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        x2.append(nume2)
    #print(f'Grafico 2 {x2}')
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x2[0]) < 3:
        y_fix2.append(int(x2[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x2[0]) >= 3 and int(x2[0]) < 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x2[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c2 in x2[1:]:

        if int(c2) < 3 :

            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color= 'green', left=y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)
            
        if int(c2) > 3 and int(c2) < 5:
        
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='yellow', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)

        if int(c2) >= 5:
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='red', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)


    #plt.show()

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, grafico_1, interval = 3000, frames=100)
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, grafico_2, interval = 3000, frames=100)

# Embed the figures into Tkinter using FigureCanvasTkAgg
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y= 460)


canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y = 530)

root.mainloop()
```

I could remove the values from my x and y axes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (in brief, provide the shortest possible code that reproduces the issue). The longer your code the less likely you are to get a response since people don't want to put in the effort of digging through all your code to find your mistake. You may even figure out the issue while going through and condensing/simplifying the code into a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question looks good, but it would be great if you could choose a more descriptive title for it, so it easier to find it so it is more likely other preople find it if they have similar problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question looks good, but it would be great if you could choose a more descriptive title for it, so it easier to find it so it is more likely other preople find it if they have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Remove axis tick marks on plot when using it with Tkinter. You should work directly with the axes objects (b1 and b ) rather than using plt.yticks([]).

```
fig1, b1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 0.5), dpi = 80,)
b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
b1.set_yticks([])  

fig2, b2 = plt.subplots(figsize= (10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
b2.set_yticks([])  
...
...

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y= 460)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y = 530)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can I do it? Could you show me please

Comment: I put your code but still appear the y axis values.

Comment: Please remove the erroneous calls  `b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)` and `b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)`.